# Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError()

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I was working on a project and everything was working fine, suddenly my app crashed because of this error :

```
Warning: %s: Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError(). 
In that method, return a state update to display an error message or fallback UI., RootErrorBoundary
```

The error is in these files :

```
* src/config/routes.js:31:27 in <unknown>
* src/modules/auth/actions.js:69:29 in <unknown>
```

in the line which contains _this.setState for routes.js :

```
componentDidMount() {
    let _this = this;
    store.dispatch(checkLoginStatus((isLoggedIn) => {
        _this.setState({isReady: true, isLoggedIn});
    }));
}
```

and in the line which contains callback(isLoggedIn) for actions.js :

```
export function checkLoginStatus(callback) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            let isLoggedIn = (user !== null);

            if (isLoggedIn) {
                //get the user object from the Async storage
                AsyncStorage.getItem('user', (err, user) => {
                    if (user === null) isLoggedIn = false //set the loggedIn value to false
                    else dispatch({type: t.LOGGED_IN, data: JSON.parse(user)})

                    callback(isLoggedIn);
                });
            } else {
                dispatch({type: t.LOGGED_OUT});
                callback(isLoggedIn);
            }
        });
    };
}
```

please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Do you have/use an error boundary component somewhere (probably near the root) in your app (i.e. `rootErrorBoundary`)?  Does it implement `getDerivedStateFromError`?  React's errorBoundary interface changed a bit in one of the recent updates.  Can you include the code for `rootErrorBoundary`?

Comment: no i don't have any code for rootErrorBoundary.

Comment: and now i have another error on the same lines : Invariant Violation: The navigation prop is missing for this navigator

Comment: Well, you have two lines in your action.js that are `callback(isLoggedIn);`, do you know which is called?  What is the value of `isLoggedIn` that is passed?  Can you post code related to the new error you're now seeing?

Comment: the error is in the same lines as before. but i don't know how it's working now. i changed nothing but still weird how everything is working fine now.

Answer (score -9):

I solved it by clearing app data

Comment: Can you elaborate on what specifically you encountered and the steps you took to solve the problem? Perhaps for someone who is searching for a solution but isn't familiar with the setup and might be confused as to what you meant by clearing app data?