# How to suppress the 'Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError()' warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, react-error-boundary

I've seen this [Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974825/error-boundaries-should-implement-getderivedstatefromerror) topic, but it doesn't help me.

I'm following the React [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) about the error boundary implementation, and it does say:

> A class component becomes an error boundary if it defines either (or
> both) of the lifecycle methods static getDerivedStateFromError() or
> componentDidCatch()

In fact, even their demo doesn't have it implemented: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa?editors=0010

The thing is: if I don't implement the `static getDerivedStateFromError() {}` method the warning appears on console:

```
Warning: TreeSearchResultsErrorBoundary: Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError(). In that method, return a state update to display an error message or fallback UI.
```

**I don't want to implement it since I'm implementing `componentDidCatch(error, info)` already, so, how can the warning be suppressed?**

This is the complete code:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.props.setHasError(true); // used to dynamically control the error state
    if (global.__SERVER__) {
      console.error(error, info);
    } else {
      logClientError({ ...error, ...info });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.hasError ? (
      <>
        <h1>Error!</h1>
      </>
    ) : (
      <>{this.props.children}</>
    );
  }
}
```

```
<ErrorBoundary
  hasError={hasError} // error storaged in component's state
  setHasError={setHasError}
>
  <ChildComponent/>
</ErrorBoundary>
```